# how to query in mongodb when key have space and dot

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

Hi I have this type of `document` in my collection having `space and dots`

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5d7e3fd812674c2234ff1983"),
        "Emp. No" : "ABC",
        "Emp. Name" : "DEEPAK DAHIYA",
        "Card No" : "24700",
        "Department" : "TEst",
        "Att Date" : "06-Jun-2019",
        "In Time" : "06-Jun-2019 11:10",
        "Out Time" : "06-Jun-2019 16:42",
        "Status" : "P       ",
        "Late By " : "02:10",
        "Early By " : "01:18",
        "Total Hour" : "05:32",
        "OT Hour" : "00:00",
        "Location" : "Consolidated",
        "id" : "f1758761dd4f5295d9075173e83353af"
    }
```

now I want to aggregate my result using aggregation. but my query not giving correct output as there is `space` and dot in my keys

```
await Dance.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: '$["Emp. No"]',
      data: {
        $addToSet: { attendance: "$['Att Date']", Status: "$Status", id: "$id" }
      }
    }
  },
  { $project: { '["Emp. No"]': "$_id", _id: 0, data: 1 } }
]);
```

Already tried square brackets but not working.

**updated query:**

```
const result = await Dance.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$Emp. No",
      data: {
        $addToSet: { attendance: "$Att Date", Status: "$Status", id: "$id" }
      }
    }
  },
  { $project: { "Emp. No": "$_id", _id: 0, data: 1 } }
]);
```

**not working correctly either**

Comment: Did you try escaping the dot.... like `"\."`

Comment: can you please tell me how to escaping dot .I have dot also in my document

Comment: Something like this `{$project: {'Emp\. No': '$_id', _id: 0, data: 1}}`

Comment: not working correctly see my update..can I remove `.` and a space before saving Data base

Comment: You can't actually have underscores and spaces in a field name....Provided a link to field name guidelines in my answer. Hope that helps?

Comment: Having `.`s and `$` in field names should be avoided altogether. [Mongo field name restrictions](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/#Restrictions-on-Field-Names). Spaces are still okay. Would suggest to transform the incoming data a save in that manner so that there are no inconsistencies.

Answer (score 1):

You [can have fields with spaces](https://mongoplayground.net/p/pJFALHG6S0A) as well as [fields with underscores](https://mongoplayground.net/p/kQVqwJzzlEf) - you just CANNOT have fields with periods in them, for example: [escaped query](https://mongoplayground.net/p/vhYEg9weO6i) and [non-escaped query](https://mongoplayground.net/p/uN_T9aWB_P6)..

Now, there are caveats with this.. As long as you're using `Mongo 3.6+` and as long as the field containing a period [is not a top level field, and is the only 'nested' field](https://mongoplayground.net/p/e5H4A8JvWMR), it will work.. If you try to use more than one nested field, [it will not work](https://mongoplayground.net/p/dX_IRTNbxVU)..

You can [read more on the subject here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/#Restrictions-on-Field-Names)...

All in all, you should just play it safe and remove the periods, but you can keep the spaces as they are allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Field names cannot contain . dots or null characters and must not start with a $ dollar sign.

More Here - https://arkusnexus.com/2016/09/12/coding-guidelines-mongodb/